# Reading words from file and storing in tree

Tags: c, debugging, tree, fgets

I'm trying to read in words from a file and store them in a tree.

```
    Dictionary newDictionary(FILE *inf)
{
    assert(inf != NULL);
    int i;
    char word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];
    Dictionary dict = malloc(sizeof(DictionaryRep));
    dict->tree = newTree(); 

    while (fgets(word,MAX_WORD_SIZE,inf) != NULL) {
        int n = strlen(word);
        word[n-1] = '\0'; 
        if (strcmp(word,"") != 0 && strlen(word) > 2 && strlen(word) < 7) {
            for(i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++){
                if(word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z'){
                    word[i] += ' ';
                }                    
            }  
        TreeInsert(dict->tree,word);
        }
    }     printf("%d\n",TreeNumNodes(dict->tree));         
    return dict;
}
```

What this code ends up doing is: read in one word from the file, store it, then read the next word, store it and so on. However, it doesn't seem to build a tree. It prints 1 from TreeNumNodes and also when I ask it to show the tree it always prints one word, then the next word and so on as fgets progresses through the file.

Implementation of TreeInsert:

```
Tree thisTree;
typedef char *Key;
typedef Key Item; 

void TreeInsert(Tree t, Item it)
{
    thisTree = t;
    t->root = insertRB(t->root, it,0);
        t->root->colour = BLACK;
}


Link insertRB(Link t, Item it, int inRight){
    if (t == NULL) return newNode(it,RED);
    // node is a 4-node; lift it
    if (isRed(t->L) && isRed(t->R)) {
        t->colour = RED;
        t->L->colour = BLACK;
        t->R->colour = BLACK;
    }
    int diff = cmp(key(it),key(t->value));
    if (diff == 0)
        t->value = it;
    else if (diff < 0) {
        t->L = insertRB(t->L, it, 0);
        if (isRed(t) && isRed(t->L) && inRight){

            t = rotateR(t);

        }
        if (isRed(t->L) && isRed(t->L->L)) {

            t = rotateR(t);
            t->colour = BLACK;
            t->R->colour = RED;
        }
    } else if (diff > 0) {
        t->R = insertRB(t->R, it, 1);
        if (isRed(t) && isRed(t->R) && !inRight){

            t = rotateL(t);
        }
        if (isRed(t->R) && isRed(t->R->R)) {

            t = rotateL(t);
            t->colour = BLACK;
            t->L->colour = RED;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: So, what you are saying is that either your `TreeInsert` or your `TreeNumNodes` function seems wrong?

Comment: @Jongware I was supplied with those codes so I don't think they would be wrong and the error should like in newDictionary

Comment: Were you supplied with a header file or function declarations? If so, please show the one for `TreeInsert`.

Comment: @Jongware I edited it in

Comment: try `TreeInsert(dict->tree,word);` chagne to `TreeInsert(dict->tree,strdup(word));` (or something else)